# How to list the folders/files of a file.tar.gz file inside a file.tar

Tags: linux, tar, suse

I need to list the folder/files inside a `certs.tar.gz` which is inside file.tar without extracting them.

```
[root@git test]# tar -tf file.tar
./
./product/
./product/.git/
./product/.git/refs/
./product/.git/refs/heads/
./Release/add_or_modify.sh
./certs.tar.gz
[root@git test]#
```

Comment: From where you need the list ? From a shell command ? An executable ? If you just need to have the list from a shell to see what's inside, give a try to some file manager (Midnight Commander or a gui based file manager)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to use and condition:

```
tar -xf abc.tar "abc.tar.gz" && tar -ztvf abc.tar.gz
```

Explanation:

**For listing of files we use**

If file is of type **tar.gz**:

```
tar -ztvf file.tar.gz
```

If file is of type **tar**:

```
tar -tvf file.tar
```

If file is of type **tar.bz2**:

```
tar -jtvf file.tar.bz2
```

You can also **search** for files in any of the above commands. e.g:

```
tar -tvf file.tar.bz2 '*.txt'
```

**For extracting files we use**

```
tar -xf file.tar
```

In these commands,

- t: List the contents of an archive.
- v: Verbosely list files processed    (display detailed information).
- z: Filter the archive through gzip so    that we can open compressed 
  (decompress) .gz tar file.
- j: Filter archive through bzip2, use to decompress .bz2 files.
- f filename: Use archive file called filename.
- x: Extract all files from given tar, but when passed with a filename
  will extract only matching files

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/list-the-contents-of-a-tar-or-targz-file/